# My program is not printing out the message I want

Tags: python, python-2.7, primes

I have written a prime number program and I'm having a trouble with printing out the message "Neither prime nor a composite" as below. I think my code is fine as it is. I'd highly appreciate any comment on this issue. Thank you, in advance

```
def prime_number():
    a = input("Please enter a number:")

    x = True
    s = 0
    for i in range(2, a):
            while x:
               if a%i == 0:
                   x = False
               elif s:
                        print s,"Neither a prime nor a composite"
               else:
                   x = True


    if x:
        print a,"is a prime number."
    elif s:
        print s,"Neither a prime nor a composite"
    else:
        print a,"is not a prime number."



prime_number()
```

Comment: I have trouble understanding your code, why won't you name your variables in a meaningful way instead of x,s,a ?

Comment: Also can you include after i enter some value for a what are you are expecting for prime and composite.

Comment: Can you also give me an examlle of "Neither a prime nor a composite" numbers.

Comment: @TanveerAlam It's just the output that I typed above. elif s:
                        print s,"Neither a prime nor a composite"

Comment: Just try elif s == 0. As 0 denaotes False in python that is why it is never getting inside of that code block.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `s` will stay equall to `0` which is equall to `False` forever, so there is no way that Your code is going to print `"Neither a prime nor a composite"`

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But there is an If statement not to make it stay equal to 0 forever.. I guess It doesn't work...?

Comment: Both Your lines that do anything with `s` are just print lines, there is no variable setting. `s = 0` this sets `s` to be equall 0 forever, `elif s:
                        print s,"Neither a prime nor a composite"` this only prints `s` when a statement `if s` is `True` which is if `s` is nearly anything else than `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Just like Chantwaffle said, you'll never get s equal to anything else than 0, because there's no code changing it to anything else. Also, if a <= 2 you'll never enter this for loop, and elif s is always False, since s is defined as 0 at the beginning. Rewrite that code thinking of what you want to achieve and what should be done to get it. Repair logic of this code.